# What reads /etc/iproute2/rt_tables

Tags: linux, iproute

To do policy routeing, one needs to add a routing table to `/etc/iproute2/rt_tables`. I was wondering how this gets read. Is it read by the kernel, or is it read by the iproute2 userspace tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just the flat file used by the `iproute2` utilities which translates user friendly names given on the command line into integer values used by the kernel. It's just to maintain a consistent mapping of "this name is this integer"

Answer (score 1):

Not directly by the kernel but the user-pace tools iproute2. The user space tools then interact with kernel through system call interface.

Taking a look at the source of the route command can be good advice. The source code for the actual kernel route updates can be found in src/linux/kernel_routes.c.

The header-file bits/ioctls.h declares the ioctl commands needed to manipulate kernel routes, while the net/route.h header-file conditions the data-structures needed to pass the route information to the kernel.